# What is The Fourier Transform Formula for 1/(j*pi*t) Types?

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, frequency-response, fourier, frequency-domain

I have old homework and solution of that but i didn't understand actually solution. Because i didn't see continous-time fourier transform formula for that.

$g(t)$=$\frac{1}{j\pi*t}$ and it asks fourier transform of that.

This is table which i try to find for solution, but i didn't see any formula for the above type:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's line seven, the FT of a unit step, $u(t)$. the signum function is just a unit step scaled and shifted.

$$sgn(t) = 2u(t)-1$$

The signum function is mean free so the $-1$ step eliminates $\pi \delta (\omega)$ term.

Keep in mind that the inverse FT is almost the same as the forward FT (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem)

Comment: But line 7 formula doesn't have $\pi$? How we eliminated $\pi$ in $g(t)$?

Comment: I believe your solution is wrong. The inverse FT of $sgn(-\omega)$ is $\frac{2}{jt}$ not $\frac{1}{j\pi t}$

Comment: Probably, it is. Now it makes sense. Thanks. But i'm asking for clarification. If -1 eliminates $πδ(ω)$, $u(t)-1$=$\frac{1}{jt}$. So for the $\pi$ part, answer shouldn't be $\frac{u(t)-1}{π}$?

Comment: Correct answer should be $\frac{sgn(-\omega)}{2\pi}$ or $\frac{u(-\omega)-1/2}{\pi}$